# Acceptable library to extract .Tar files for an iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

please help me to understand that which library will be the best to extract .tar files in an iphone application.

on googling i have found in few posts that libacrchive can be used but another posts says that it will be problematic if you go to upload your app on App store.

Please suggest a suitable library for this purpose.

Comment: libarchive is released under the New BSD License, which is compatible with the iOS Developer's Agreement.  The licenses to watch out for which I believe are *not* compatible are the GNU General Public License (GPL) and the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL).  But IANAL, so do not take this as legal advice.

Comment: @Adam...thanks... yes i will check for that.
Do you know any other library which can solve my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I write a lib exactly for that: extracting standard tar file without zlib compression.

https://github.com/mhausherr/Light-Untar-for-iOS

My lib take just few lines when libarchive heights 4.7Mb.
Full explanation here: http://blog.octo.com/en/untar-on-ios-the-pragmatic-way/

Comment: Please, add unzipping to your lib. It will be priceless!